# Angular net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angular, laravel, api, http, https

i have in

1. Angular application (front).
2. Api Laravel (Back).
3. Domaine SSL (https).

Like this when i disable SSL on my server it work with **http**:

```
        let url = 'http://api.hamham.me/public/api/items';

         this.http.get(url, {
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json'),
            }).subscribe((res) => {
          this.items = res;
        });
```

but when i use **https**
it give me this error

> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[Error sceenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Vfp.png)

please help me how can i get data from my API with http**s**

Comment: You likely haven't configured your SSL cert correctly. This question lacks substantial detail. You need to keep investigating and provide people with a detailed problem that can be solved. A screenshot of a generic error, will not be likely to get you any good answers.

Comment: This post can help you to debug this problem.   https://dev.to/jwp/signalr-negotiation-failure-status-code-0-2mj7